# How to insert JSON bulk data in Neo4j?

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

**I am having trouble inserting a large number of JSON data in Neo4j**

If I insert more data in Neo4j means it will take more time to run it and makes my performance very slow and I have to wait for 10-15 mins for the complete process of insertion.

Is there any solution or any suggestion on how to insert bulk data? I have used merge query while inserting the JSON data and there is no unique value so I picked some combinations to make object model in merge query.

`dir_port`
`sym_dev`
`ini_tiator_group_name`
`host_lun`
`sym_metrix_id`

(*There is no unique constraint in this query to get object model we have used combinations of values I have mentioned above*)

This is my query:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:<path>')YIELD value AS row   
    UNWIND row.symdev AS symdevs    
    MERGE (accesssymdev:symaccess_symdev {
      sym_dev:symdevs.sym_dev,  
      ini_tiator_group_name:symdevs.ini_tiator_group_name,  
      host_lun:symdevs.host_lun,  
      symid:symdevs.sym_metrix_id,  
      dir_port:symdevs.dir_port
    })   
    ON CREATE SET   
      accesssymdev.attr_percentage = symdevs.attr_percentage,  
      accesssymdev.cap_mb = toFloat(symdevs.cap_mb),  
      accesssymdev.physicaldevicename = symdevs.physicaldevicename;
```

This is my sample JSON value:

> ```
> {
>   "dir_port": "011:000",
>   "attr_percentage": "(m)",
>   "sym_metrix_id": "123456",
>   "sym_dev": "05467",
>   "ini_tiator_group_name": "cluster_abcdefgh_mnop_sss1",
>   "host_lun": "52",
>   "cap(mb)": "246369",
>   " physicaldevicename": "not visible"
> },
> {
>   "dir_port": "001:000",
>   "attr_percentage": "(m)",
>   "sym_metrix_id": "123456",
>   "sym_dev": "03as1",
>   "ini_tiator_group_name": "cluster_abcdefgh_mnop_sss1",
>   "host_lun": "54",
>   "cap(mb)": "210000",
>   " physicaldevicename": "not visible"
> },
> ```

Comment: And you a neo4j `unique constraint` on the field `symid` for the label `access` ? Can you provide the `EXPLAIN` of the query ?

Comment: Here i have updated some changes verify this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a **node Key** or an **index** or a **constraint** on your `MERGE`, then more data you will have, more time the `MERGE` will take.

In your case, the best is to create a node key : `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:symaccess_symdev) ASSERT (n.sym_dev, n.ini_tiator_group_name, n.host_lun, n.symid, n.dir_port) IS NODE KEY`